# Push to dotcloud with "/" in branch name

Tags: dotcloud

I've been attempting to push to dotcloud using:

```
dotcloud push --git -b tim/feature-name
```

However, it says that it's unable to find branch "feature-name"

I ended up creating a workaround for my deployment by creating a branch without the forward slash and deploying that for the meantime.

Does anyone have a solution for this or am I supposed to avoid forward slashes in branch names for dotcloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a bug with the dotcloud-cli, you should submit a ticket here: https://github.com/dotcloud/dotcloud-cli